# How to do load testing for 100 000 users to play a quiz game

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

How can multiple users play one quiz in JMeter? What validation should be applied for that?

I tried to play the quiz with single user credentials and it was successful, but when I changed the login credentials for the same quiz, I got a 401 error, said the contest already joined, so my question is how to parameterize the quiz and what validation should be done. What is the rule to give a load for 10,000 users?

[image]

How can we set the request where multiple users join the same contest and play the quiz through JMeter, and after that how can we send request for their result in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Status 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) means **Unauthorized** so I would rather assume that there is a problem with your 2nd credentials.

So first of all double check whether the user credentials are correct using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and if the user can access the "quiz" (whatever it is) when you manually do this using a real browser. It might be permissions issue as well.

With regards to "how to parameterize" - we cannot provide a comprehensive answer without knowing the details of your "quiz", normally it should be handled by [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) or parameterization (correct credentials, unique values, etc).

When it comes to "validating" normally people use [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to ensure that the response contains the anticipated data and doesn't contain i.e. errors.

Also you definitely won't be able to simulate 100 000 virtual users from a single machine so keep in mind that you will need to go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

At 100,000 concurrent users there is enough risk present to support any tool on the market, particularly tools that have a strong proven track record in the 100,000 to 1M user arena with full monitoring and analysis.

Second, as you are struggling with tool basics, you should not be running a 100,000 user test.  The risk is sufficient that it should be an experienced team of individuals conducting such a test.

Thirdly, the concepts you are struggling with are tool foundation level to identify and address dynamic data

1. Record twice, same credentials.  Examine the differences between the recordings.  These amount to session, state, time, etc...  Address these with your tool features
2. Record a third time.  Change Credentials.  This time the changes (excepting the ones identified in (1) above) are directly related to account selection.   Address these using your tool features.

You will need to benchmark the weight of your users on a load generator to understand how many load generators you will neeed.  Monitor the fine resource utilization on your load generator for 1, then 10, then 100 users.   Then calculate the resource pool sizing for your 100,000 users.   You can safely assume that you are at least 20 generators at 5,000 users apiece for very large generators and very small resource footprint virtual users.  You may be at 40 or 50 load generators depending upon the resource requirements of each user.

You don't want to "max out" your load generators.  You want them undersubscribed.  As you move beyond 80% resource pool utilization on memory and CPU you have overhead that will slow your users.  You will not get 100% utlization ona collission domain like network.  Your disk can easily become a drag anchor depending upon your log level, slowing every user

Everything is non-trivial at the load levels you are asking to go to.  Your management owes you several strong mentors to help you build a solid test, test bed, monitoring framework, analysis framework, and mature your skills rapidly.

Always keep in mind, the value of what we do is not the test.  The test simply produces data.  The value is in the analysis of the data for a recommendation to improve the performance of the system under test.  To that end you need many more capabilities than simple load throwing.  You need monitoring of the finite resource pool of the application, access to the application logs, an interface/application that facilitates analysis of the results (bringing together times and resource utilization levels), and reporting.